# Function call in C with array

Tags: c, arrays, function

I have a function that takes array 1 and copies/manipulates it to array 2. Basically what it does is take the user input in array one, lets say (2, 3, 3) and array 2 is stored as (2, 0, 3, 0, 3). I know this works because it worked without implementing a function but sadly I have to have one. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to call the function, I believe I don't need a return since its a void and not returning a value. Below is my code any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insert0(int n, int a1[], int a2[]);

int main() {

int i = 0;
int n = 0;
int a1[n];
int a2[2*n];

printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ //adds values to first array
        scanf("%d",&a1[i]);
}

insert0(); //call function which is wrong and I cannot get anything to work

for( i = 0; i < n*2; i++){ //prints array 2
        printf("%d", a2[i]);
        }

void insert0 (int n, int a1[], int a2[]){ //inserts 0's between each number

for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        a2[i+i] = a1[i];
        a2[i+i+1] = 0;
        }
}
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. It's too messy to take the time to read it. Because it requires extra effort.

Comment: You don't pass any parameters to insert0().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Modifying `n` after declaraing `a1` and `a2` won't magically increase their size. Declare `a1` and `a2` *after* reading the size into `n` to use variable-length arrays.
- You must pass proper arguments to call `insert0`.
- Defining functions inside functions is GCC extension and you shouldn't do that unless it is required.
- `a2` should have `n*2 - 1` elements, not `n*2` elements.
- After moving it out of `main()`, `i` is not declared in `insert0`, so you have to declare it.
- You should check if readings are successful.

Corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void insert0(int n, int a1[], int a2[]);

int main() {

        int i = 0;
        int n = 0;

        printf("Enter the length of the array: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1){
                puts("read error for n");
                return 1;
        }
        if(n <= 0){
                puts("invalid input");
                return 1;
        }

        int a1[n];
        int a2[2*n-1];

        printf("Enter the elements of the array: ");

        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){ //adds values to first array
                if(scanf("%d", &a1[i]) != 1){
                        printf("read error for a1[%d]\n", i);
                        return 1;
                }
        }

        insert0(n, a1, a2);

        for( i = 0; i < n*2-1; i++){ //prints array 2
                printf("%d", a2[i]);
        }
}
void insert0 (int n, int a1[], int a2[]){ //inserts 0's between each number
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
                a2[i+i] = a1[i];
                if (i+1 < n){ // don't put 0 after the last element
                        a2[i+i+1] = 0;
                }
        }
}
```